# Complex javascript frustum of a cone calculator wont calculate

Tags: javascript

This is my first time using javascript and I'm trying to make a calculator that tells you the volume of a conical frustum using this formula V = (1/3) * π * h * (r12 + r22 + (r1 * r2)) here is my attempt but the out.value doesn't seem to want to update. In all likelihood I've been staring at it too long and am missing something simple but I just can't seem to see it, any help appreciated greatly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateOutput() {
var form = document.getElementById("calc");
var out = form.elements["z"]
var num1 = parseInt(form.elements["h"].value);
var num2 = parseInt(form.elements["s"].value);
var num3 = parseInt(form.elements["r"].value);
var num4 = parseInt(form.elements["g"].value);
var num5 = math.pow(num3,2);
var num6 = math.pow(num4,2);
out.value = (1/3)*3.1459*num1*[num5+num6+(num3*num4)];
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="calc">
<input name="h" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="s" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="r" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="g" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="updateOutput()" />
<div class="equals"> = </div>
<output name="z">0</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var num5 = math.pow(num3,2);
var num6 = math.pow(num4,2);
```

The function is `Math.pow`, not `math.pow` (capital M).

Also, this seems to work right now, but it's certainly an odd way of doing it:

```
(1/3)*3.1459*num1*[num5+num6+(num3*num4)];
```

Square brackets (`[]`) are not parentheses - they make an array. You're multiplying by the array. As it happens, the numerical value of a single-item array is that item, but i still wouldn't rely on this.

```js
function updateOutput() {
var form = document.getElementById("calc");
var out = form.elements["z"]
var num1 = parseInt(form.elements["h"].value);
var num2 = parseInt(form.elements["s"].value);
var num3 = parseInt(form.elements["r"].value);
var num4 = parseInt(form.elements["g"].value);
var num5 = Math.pow(num3,2);
var num6 = Math.pow(num4,2);
out.value = (1/3)*3.1459*num1*(num5+num6+(num3*num4));
}
```

```html
<form id="calc">
<input name="h" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="s" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="r" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="g" type="number" value="0" />
<input name="calculate" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="updateOutput()" />
<div class="equals"> = </div>
<output name="z">0</output>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, still can't get it to run on the page but that's probably user error